# Awk gensub() does not match regex

Tags: regex, linux, unix, awk

I need to modify a number of files to replace part of it. An example of the file content is shown below.

```
    <title>block-quote-line</title>
    <path d="M11.86,16.55a4.31,4.31,0,0,0-2.11.56,14.44,14.44,0,0,1,4.36-6,1.1,1.1,0,0,0-1.4-1.7c-4,3.25-5.78,7.75-5.78,10.54A5.08,5.08,0,0,0,10,24.58a4.4,4.4,0,0,0,1.88.44,4.24,4.24,0,1,0,0-8.47Z" class="clr-i-outline clr-i-outline-path-1"></path><path d="M23,16.55a4.29,4.29,0,0,0-2.11.56,14.5,14.5,0,0,1,4.35-6,1.1,1.1,0,1,0-1.39-1.7c-4,3.25-5.78,7.75-5.78,10.54a5.08,5.08,0,0,0,3,4.61A4.37,4.37,0,0,0,23,25a4.24,4.24,0,1,0,0-8.47Z" class="clr-i-outline clr-i-outline-path-2"></path>
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="36" height="36" fill-opacity="0"/>
</svg>
```

The `class="clr-i-outline clr-i-outline-path-[]"` part of the file needs to be modified to `fill = "#000000".`

The regex matching the string looks as follows

```
(class=clr-i-outline clr-i-outline-path-[1-9])
```

Now I need to integrate this regex into a command, which is however not working.

```
awk -v regex="(class=\"clr-i-outline clr-i-outline-path-\[1-9\]\")" -v trgt="fill = \"#AB7C94\"" '{ gensub (/regex/, trgt, "g" ) ./test.svg}'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Trying to use a variable inside a regexp constant. See https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Regexp and in particular https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Computed-Regexps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `test.svg` is the file you're aiming to replace:

```
awk -v regex='class="clr-i-outline clr-i-outline-path-[1-9]"' -v trgt='fill = "#AB7C94"' '{ print gensub(regex, trgt, "g" )}' test.svg
```

Or:

```
awk -v regex='class="clr-i-outline clr-i-outline-path-[1-9]"' -v trgt='fill = "#AB7C94"' '{ gsub(regex, trgt)}1' test.svg
```

Both would work on GNU awk.

You can use signle quotes `'` to enclose the string which has double quotes inside, and you don't need to escape `"` and `[]` inside single quotes.
Also when referring the variable as regex, just use variable name, not `/variable/`.

And you didn't print the output, `gensub` won't change the thing it replaced but will return it, so you just print it.
On the other hand, `gsub` will change, but won't return the thing it changed, you can print afterwards.